# "from" clause and "select" clause return differents JSON formats

Tags: json, hibernate

I have a question. What is the difference between

```
books = session.createQuery("from Book b").list();
```

and

```
books = session.createQuery("select b.id, b.title, b.author, b.isbn, b.genre, b.price, b.amount from Book b").list();
```

because I receive different JSON format. The first one returns:

> [{"id":1,"isbn":"83-7298-723-8","title":"Hand of God. The Life of
>   Diego Maradona","price":32.1,"author":"Jimmy
>   Burn","amount":13,"genre":"Sport"},{"id":2,"isbn":"978-83-11-10881-3","title":"Beginners
>   Guide to Weight Training","price":33.4,"author":"Oliver
>   Roberts","amount":4,"genre":"Sport"}]

and the second one:

> [[1,"Hand of God. The Life of Diego Maradona","Jimmy
>   Burn","83-7298-723-8","Sport",32.1,13],[2,"Beginners Guide to Weight
>   Training","Oliver Roberts","978-83-11-10881-3","Sport",33.4,4]]

so there is a difference with [ and { and the order is different.

Comment: According to [the spec](http://www.json.org/) `[]` is an array `{}` is an object. So first case is an array of objects and second case is an array of arrays. In the second case the order is as you've specified it in the query and you're getting the columns you requested (which the result does not specify by name).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference between the two queries is that :

1. The first one returns a `List<Book>` as you set `from Book b`, so it will return the whole `Book` object.
2. While the second one returns a `List<Object[]>`as you set `select b.id, b.title, b.author, b.isbn, b.genre, b.price, b.amount from Book b`, so for each result the query will return an array of objects where every attribute is returned as `Object` no matter what was its type. And in this case you will get an `Object[]` even if you select all the columns from your Entity.

And that explains the difference between the two JSON outputs you got.

**Reference:**

You can see from **[Hibernte documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html/ch16.html)** that:

- [Select clause](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html/ch16.html#queryhql-select) : return selected objects in a query result set
- [From clause](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html/ch16.html#queryhql-from) : return class instances